# No keyword with name "launch browser" found Robot Framework

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, robotframework

I have 2 files: in userkeywords.robot I have the test case file as follows:

```
\*\*\* Settings \*\*\*
Library     SeleniumLibrary
Library     OperatingSystem
Resource    ../Resources/resources.robot

\*\*\* Variables \*\*\*
${url}      https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=it
${browser}  chrome

\*\*\* Test Cases \*\*\*
TC1
${PageTitle}=   launch browser  ${url}      ${browser}
input text      id:username     user
input text      id:password     mypass
```

In the other: resources.robot I have all the keywords which I separated from the main file:

```
\*\*\* Settings \*\*\*
Library     SeleniumLibrary
Library     OperatingSystem

\*\*\* Keywords \*\*\*
launch browser
\[Arguments\]       ${appurl}   ${browser}
open browser    ${url}      ${browser}
maximize browser window

    ${title}=   get title
    
    [Return]    ${title}
```

For some reason I get the following error message:

```
PS C:\\temp\\TestCases\> robot .\\userkeywords.robot
TC1                                                                   | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'launch browser' found.
```

I am using VS code

I tried to put both files in the same folder but still get the error

Comment: Is the indentation in your files exactly as shown in the samples above? Because it's off, and the escape chars (\\) are not needed. Please note I've edited it just to separate the code blocks, but edit it further to be the same as in your source files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a line in your Settings section that says

```
Library | SeleniumLibrary
```

and you might also need to run

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-seleniumlibrary
```

Comment: Regretfully I don't think it's as simple as that - the library is imported, and it looks like it's installed (withe the lack of an exception that unknown library is being imported).

Answer (score 0):

You need to recheck where your resources.robot file present.
I suspect `Resource    ../Resources/resources.robot` causing this issue.
Also, these '' all over may be something not present in your code, right?